# How to filter dataframe in r based on multiple conditions

Tags: r

The dataframe below has 3 columns. So first there is a need to filter only rows that has 0 in colb and then filter values in colc greater than cola

```
asd <- data.frame(cola = c(34,56,46,76,54), colb = c(0, 0, 0, 5, 54), colc = c(35, 53, 47, 98, 95))
```

Expected output

```
  cola colb colc
1   34    0   35
3   46    0   47
```

Comment: There are more than a dozen Qs on SO asking to subset a data frame by condition. What have you researched? What have you tried? `asd[asd$colb == 0 & asd$cola < asd$colc, ]`

Comment: `base::subset`, `dplyr::filter`, and Friede's suggestion are one of the first things discussed in any R tutorial that starts with "hello, this is R". Please ask your questions, but you are expected to have done some research prior to doing so, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3358272.

Comment: `filter(asd, colb == 0 & cola < colc)` and `dplyr::filter(asd, colb == 0 & cola < colc)` are the equivalent to Friede's `[`-code (which is canonical base R code).